# Does this seem right?

Tags: javascript, time, if-statement, alert

So I made this a while ago (I believe with help from here but I can't remember -irrelevant) for class. Its supposed to return a message based on the time of day and then a random message. The random message part works fine. Its the Time of Day message I'm confused about. Tell me what you think... does it look right?

```
var hr = new Date();

if (hr < 12) {
    alert("Good Morning");
}
if ((hr - 12) < 6) {
    alert("Good Afternoon");
}
if (hr >= 18) {
    alert("Good Evening");
}

msg = new Array
msg[1]="how are you"
msg[2]="whazzup"
msg[3]="how have you been"
msg[4]="how has your day been going"
msg[5]="hey y'all"

random_num = (Math.round((Math.random()*4)+1))

alert(msg[random_num]);
```

All help and suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [else if](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: this looks like homework.. is this homework? if it is you should tag it [tag:homework]

Comment: [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [its methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods_2) :)

Answer (score 3):

You should be calling `getHours()` to return the hour. Your `hr` is actually a `Date` object:

```
var d = new Date();
var hr = d.getHours();

// Etc...
if (hr < 12) {
    alert("Good Morning");
}
if ((hr - 12) < 6) {
    alert("Good Afternoon");
}
if (hr >= 18) {
    alert("Good Evening");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hr = (new Date()).getHours();
if (hr < 12)
{
   alert("Good Morning");
}
else if (hr < 18)
{
   alert("Good Afternoon");
}
else if (hr >= 18)
{
   alert("Good Evening");
}
```

For the array:

```
msg = [null]; //start off with index 0 as null
msg.push("how are you");
msg.push("whazzup");
msg.push("how have you been");
msg.push("how has your day been going");
msg.push("hey y'all");
```

Comment: damn, should have refreshed before I posted... *my array is built up differently.. I'll keep it*

Comment: @rlemon might want to remove the `+1` in your answer bc then u will never reach the `0`'th index.

Comment: @Neal you already have an array constructor why do you push instead of just populating with that data your pushing? it just seems unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 0):

Because your comparing the same expression to multiple outcomes I would recommend a switch statement because it is much cleaner, and provides greater flexibility instead of a bunch of spaghetti code, with else if's and stuff.

Comment: with the limited number of cases described a switch statement will in fact run slower. marginal difference, but difference none-the-less

Comment: as a general rule if else-if else is fine

Answer (score 0):

```
// proper way to get the current hour
var hr = new Date().getHours();

// use if elseif
if(hr < 12) {
    alert("Good Morning");
} else if(hr < 18) {
    alert("Good Afternoon");
} else {
    alert("Good Evening");
}

// use var so we don't pollute
var msg = [
    "how are you",
    "whazzup",
    "how have you been",
    "how has your day been going",
    "hey y'all"
];

var random_num = Math.round(Math.random()*4);

alert(msg[random_num]);
```

Comment: remove the `+1` from the random number!

Comment: also use `msg.length` (and `Math.floor`) instead of `4` for the random in case the size of the array changes ^_^

Comment: and if you wanted to get ***really fancy*** you could add `var message = "";` after `var hr..` and replace the first three alerts with `message += "Good Morning|Afternoon|Evening"` (changing the time of day respectively) then change `var random_num = Math.round(Math.random()*4);` to `message += " " + msg[Math.round(Math.random()*4)];` and finally the last alert to `alert(message);` voilà~!

Comment: yea to be honest neal i didn't really pay to much attention to the math stuff.

Comment: Also, `Math.round(Math.random()*4)` will return 1,2,3 twice as often as 0,4. (0 = 0 to 0.5, 1 = 0.5 to 1.5, etc) `Math.floor(Math.random()*5)` will return more even distribution.